# problem with glib-2.0 when cross compiling for arm32bit on 64bit ubuntu

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling, petalinux

when I try to cross compile my GStreamer pipeline to run it on Petalinux build, it loads the 64bit libraries while the host is a 32bit arm.

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc PIPEX.c -o PIPEX `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-app-1.0`
```

I get the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include/glibconfig.h:9:0,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gst.h:27,
                 from PIPEX.c:5:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h: In function ‘_GLIB_CHECKED_ADD_U64’:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:241:53: error: size of array ‘_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_0’ is negative
 #define G_STATIC_ASSERT(expr) typedef char G_PASTE (_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_, __COUNTER__)[(expr) ? 1 : -1] G_GNUC_UNUSED
                                                     ^
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:238:47: note: in definition of macro ‘G_PASTE_ARGS’
 #define G_PASTE_ARGS(identifier1,identifier2) identifier1 ## identifier2
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:241:44: note: in expansion of macro ‘G_PASTE’
 #define G_STATIC_ASSERT(expr) typedef char G_PASTE (_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_, __COUNTER__)[(expr) ? 1 : -1] G_GNUC_UNUSED
                                            ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:423:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘G_STATIC_ASSERT’
   G_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof (unsigned long long) == sizeof (guint64));
```

I've already tried installing ":i386" packages and exporting  PKG_CONFIG_PATH to /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/ but after that I get:

```
/media/mk/DATA/programs/Xilinx/SDK/2018.3/gnu/aarch32/lin/gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7.3.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lgstapp-1.0
/media/mk/DATA/programs/Xilinx/SDK/2018.3/gnu/aarch32/lin/gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7.3.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lgstbase-1.0
/media/mk/DATA/programs/Xilinx/SDK/2018.3/gnu/aarch32/lin/gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7.3.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lgstreamer-1.0
/media/mk/DATA/programs/Xilinx/SDK/2018.3/gnu/aarch32/lin/gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7.3.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
/media/mk/DATA/programs/Xilinx/SDK/2018.3/gnu/aarch32/lin/gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7.3.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You need ARM libraries if you want to build for ARM. i386 is not ARM

Comment: tnx for your response. the crosscompiler tools are provided by petalinux and they work under i386

Comment: But you are creating ARM binaries. Those need ARM libraries.

Comment: how can I get the ARM libraries?